# Blogger API v3 add Search Description

Tags: python, google-api, blogger, google-api-client, google-blogger-api

**I can't find how to add the Search Description using the Blogger API V3. Is it possible to add search description using blogger API ?**

Comment: Did you find the correct way to do that? I am also can't find a way to set a custom URL using API v3 nor add labels...

Comment: {"content":"your content",  "title": "your title",  "labels": "YOUR LABELS"} use this for labels